# SQL Pass node from XML Parameter to a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm currently working on a stored procedure, where I want to take one node from a XML parameter and pass it to a function. This is the format of the parameter:

```
    @parameters AS XML =

'     <parameters>
            <vkorgs>
                  <vkorg>1010</vkorg>
                  <vkorg>2400</vkorg>
            </vkorgs>
            <dates>
                  <datefrom>20150701</datefrom>
                  <dateto>20150805</dateto>
            </dates>
      </parameters>
'
```

This is the function call (with examplary xml):

```
sap.werks('<method>Distribution</method>
                         <vkorgs>
                               <vkorg>2800</vkorg>
                         </vkorgs>
                         <showVkorg>0</showVkorg>')
```

What I need to do now is to extract the "vkorgs" node and enrich it with the "method" and "showVkorg" node and pass the result to the "sap.werks" function. I've tried several ways with 'FOR XML' but neither gave me the expected results. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

From the XML in the @parameters variable I need the "vkorgs" node (only this node) to pass it to another function. What I tried so far is this:

```
 declare  @parameters AS XML =

'     <parameters>
            <vkorgs>
                  <vkorg>1010</vkorg>
                  <vkorg>2400</vkorg>
            </vkorgs>
            <dates>
                  <datefrom>20150701</datefrom>
                  <dateto>20150805</dateto>
            </dates>
      </parameters>
'
SELECT  1 as TAG, null as PARENT, c.value('.', 'int') AS [vkorgs!1!vkorg!ELEMENT]
FROM @parameters.nodes('/parameters/vkorgs/vkorg') AS t(c)
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

This outputs the folloowing:

```
<vkorgs>
  <vkorg>1010</vkorg>
</vkorgs>
<vkorgs>
  <vkorg>2400</vkorg>
</vkorgs>
```

This is ner to what I expect, which would be the following:

```
<vkorgs>
  <vkorg>1010</vkorg>
  <vkorg>2400</vkorg>
</vkorgs>
```

After I have this I would need to add two other nodes

```
<method>Distribution</method>
```

And

```
<showVkorg>0</showVkorg>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<vkorgs>
      <vkorg>1010</vkorg>
      <vkorg>2400</vkorg>
    </vkorgs>
<method>Distribution</method>
<showVkorg>0</showVkorg>
```

The last step would be to pass it all to a function named "sap.werks" like this:

```
sap.werks('<vkorgs>
          <vkorg>1010</vkorg>
          <vkorg>2400</vkorg>
        </vkorgs>
    <method>Distribution</method>
    <showVkorg>0</showVkorg>')
```

Or if it would be possible to store the results in a variable I could also call it like this:

```
sap.werks(@XML)
```

@XML would hold the resulting XML.

Comment: Could you please give us an example of what you tried and explain better what does mean enrich with "method" and "showVkorg"?

Comment: I can't see how to relate the first SQL snippet with the 2nd one. You really need to elaborate more on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited my question to clear things up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is the following.  This will leave you with the data you want in an XML variable, and you can do what you need with it after that (pass it to your function, etc.):

```
DECLARE @fn_param xml

SELECT @fn_param =
(
    SELECT @parameters.query('./parameters/vkorgs'), 
        'Distribution' AS method, 0 AS ShowVkorg
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
)
```

To break down what this is doing, the first column in the `SELECT` clause extracts the `vkorgs` node, and the second two columns define new elements (the element's data is the column data, the element name is the column name).  `FOR XML PATH` is a clean and simple way to get SQL Server to generate XML.  By default it would enclose the whole thing with a wrapper node, but by specifying the null string for that node you bypass that behavior.

The `TYPE` modifier causes the statement to return the `xml` datatype rather than a character string; this can be changed if it is more convenient for you to work with strings.